# Why does Perlbrew launch bash on Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: perl, perlbrew

When I run...

`perlbrew switch perl-5.16.0`

...I get...

`A sub-shell is launched with perl-5.16.0 as the activated perl. Run 'exit' to finish it.`

...then a bash prompt appears.

Is this expected behavior?
If not, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That happens when you have an improperly installed `perlbrew`. As part of the installation, you are instructed to add a command to your shell startup script, but that appears to be missing.

Add the following to your shell startup script:

```
source .../perlbrew/etc/bashrc
```

There's a similar script for `csh`.

```
source .../perlbrew/etc/cshrc
```

Comment: Thanks, ikegami, that worked perfectly. I added the source line to `~/.bash_profile`. Specifically, in case there's another Mac newbie like me: `source /Users/Username/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc`