# Switching to the system Perl using perlbrew

Tags: perl, perlbrew

First, some background.

`perlbrew` is a tool to assist with the installation of Perl into a non-standard directory (usually under your home directory).

It also helps you control which Perl installation is used when executing `perl` in an interactive shell. Switching between installations is done using `perlbrew use` and `perlbrew switch`. `perlbrew use` only affects the current shell, while `perlbrew switch` is more permanent.

```
$ perl -V:version             |  $ perl -V:version
version='5.20.0';             |  version='5.20.0';
                              |
$ perlbrew use 5.18.2t        |  $ perlbrew switch 5.18.2t
                              |
$ perl -V:version             |  $ perl -V:version
version='5.18.2';             |  version='5.18.2';
                              |
$ bash -ic 'perl -V:version'  |  $ bash -ic 'perl -V:version'
version='5.20.0';             |  version='5.18.2';
```

`perlbrew off` is used to revert to using the system Perl, but it's temporary like `perlbrew use`. Is there a way to revert to the system Perl with the permanency of `perlbrew switch`?

Comment: wow, you are really fast at answering your own question :)

Comment: @jh314, It's an SO feature. When you ask a question, there's a checkbox labeled something like "answer your own question". If you check that, an answer form appears. Both the question and the answer are submitted simultaneously.

Comment: Cool, didn't see that!  So you ask when you know the answer?

Comment: @jh314 SO's purpose is to build a database of useful Questions and Answers.  It's just as useful to share things one learns on their own using this method, yes.  Especially if it's a very specific question and therefore easily searched for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following command

```
perlbrew switch-off
```

Comment: `switch-off` wasn't always part of `perlbrew`, but this is clearly the better solution now :) The technique used by the other answer is still valuable to integrate other `perl` builds not installed by `perlbrew`, however.

Comment: Just to be explicit about that: `switch-off` was added in 0.29 (released Sept 2011), and before that, `perlbrew use system` or `perlbrew off` were implemented in 0.15 (released Dec 2010).

Answer (score 26):

To have `perlbrew` manage an installation of `perl` that wasn't installed by `perlbrew`, pick a name ("`system`" in my example) and create a link to its `bin` directory as follows:

```
cd "${PERLBREW_ROOT:-$HOME/perl5/perlbrew}"
mkdir perls/system
ln -s /usr/bin perls/system/bin
```

It will now appear in `perlbrew list`

```
$ perlbrew list
  ...
  system (5.10.1)
  5.18.2t
* 5.20.0t
  ...
```

And you'll be able to use `perlbrew use` and `perlbrew switch`.

```
$ perl -V:version
version='5.20.0';

$ perlbrew switch system

$ perl -V:version
version='5.10.1';

$ bash -ic 'perl -V:version'
version='5.10.1';
```

This works best with installations that have the same `installbin`, `installvendorbin` (if applicable) and `installsitebin` directories, as returned by

```
perl -V:'install.*bin'
```

---

By the way, a similar approach can be used to create aliases for `perlbrew` installs. For example,

```
 ln -s 5.26.1 perls/5.26           # Point to the latest release of a version.
 ln -s 5.26.1 perls/project_name   # Point to the install used by a project.
```

Comment: I followed these instructions and after running `perlbrew switch system` I got: "A sub-shell is launched with system as the activated perl. Run 'exit' to finish it."  That doesn't seem permanent...

Comment: @Marcus, You have an improperly installed `perlbrew`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11194041/589924)

Comment: Ah, nice.  Thank you @ikegami.