# Can I install perl binary with perlbrew?

Tags: perl, perlbrew

I am using perlbrew on a raspi, but I don't want to the slow processor to compile new perls. Can I install binaries with it (or other similar tools), like when I use homebrew?

Answer (score 0):

`perlbrew` isn't a package manager. It can't install whatever package it is you have.

But once you have it installed, you can manage it using `perlbrew` by following [these intructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25188576/589924).